# Trying to creat a layout whare one text view is on the left hand side and the other on the left hand side

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a a layout that will have one text view on the right, the other on the left.

I put each set of text views in a horizontal container with the width set to fill_parent.  The first text view has the gravity set to right.  The following text vie has the gravity set to right.  But both text views get drawn on the right side

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMarketName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Market Name"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last Price:"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1.0000000000 BTC"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ask Price:"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1.0000000000 BTC"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bid Price:"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1.0000000000 BTC"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textMarketName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Market Name"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Last Price:"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1.0000000000 BTC"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ask Price:"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1.0000000000 BTC"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bid Price:"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1.0000000000 BTC"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Or this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textMarketName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Market Name"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Last Price:"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1.0000000000 BTC"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Last Price:"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1.0000000000 BTC"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Last Price:"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1.0000000000 BTC"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of layout_grvity=left/right

try using alignParentLeft=true and alignParentRight=true

Hope this helps... Cheers!!